# Tensorflow with GPU speeds

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

Is there anything that affects speed other than RAM? I'm running an experiment on two different laptops, one that allocates just 300MB and another that allocates 4GB and somehow the 300MB is running faster despite being allocated less than 1/10th of the memory.

Are there potentially allocation issues for different types of nvidia cards? It's the same LSTM for both.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tensorflow is affected by the clock speed of your CPU or the characteristics of your GPU if you are running tensorflow-gpu (which parallelizes your code to run much, much faster).  Everything from the single-core performance of your GPU to its video RAM can affect your NN training speed, though it can be nonlinear -- for example, high bandwidth GPUs may not have much of a performance increase over low bandwidth GPUs on a small feedforward network.  Unless you are running multiple GPUs and if you're not trying to allocate memory to fill more than 80% of your VRam (I find usually the top 20% is full), I don't know why this would be a memory allocation issue -- lastly, I know it's been a while, so if you're still having the issue, maybe update your CUDA drivers.